# File watcher is not working without breakpoints

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have created an application, where it watches a folder(directory) for any `*.*` files. The application works when I am debugging through the VS2010 with break points.

The same application doesn't work when I remove the break point.

anything I am missing . . .

Comment: I think you could say that you are missing a code sample ;-)

Comment: It would certainly help to see some code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common issue with FSW.  A debugger helps because it slows down time.  When a process generates, say, a Change event, you typically cannot open the file right away.  The process still has the file open and has it locked.  The debugger helps because your breakpoint gives the process time to close the file.

You'll have to slow down time in your code.  Avoid spinning in the event handler, that will make you lose change notifications.  The best way to do it is by putting the path of the file in a thread-safe List<> that you try to empty with a timer.  This also helps you deal with multiple change notifications.  And UI threading problems, FSW generates its events on a threadpool thread from which you can't update a UI (but see SynchronizingObject).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know any of this. You have any links to back this up/for further reading?

Comment: The API function that makes FSW work is ReadDirectoryChangesW(), googles very well.